# LK-99: Are all conductive strong diamagnets superconductors?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

Motivated by the LK-99 material story lately, which seems to me to behave under an external magnetic field more like a strong diamagnetic compound and according to the inventors it is also electrically conducting and having more or less a sharp conductivity transition I liked to ask, is it not that what really a superconductor is?

Meaning, is a conductive strong diamagnetic material a synonym for superconductor?

Are there any other electrically conductive strong diamagnetic materials that you know that don't exhibit a superconductive transition? And if not is it then fair to say that despite if KL-99 can have any useful applications or not, that it is a legit superconductive compound anyway?

Strangely enough,  this here also claims that pyrolytic graphite is also superconductive at 27 °C https://revistapesquisa.fapesp.br/en/superconductor-at-room-temperature/ but having this property located only in some small regions inside the bulk of the material like “grains” or “islands”.

Maybe, the LK-99 is a similar case but more advanced?

Comment: At this point I'm not sure we can say much about KL-99 beyond speculation.

Comment: More importantly, copper is diamagnetic and does not show superconductivity at any temperature at normal pressures. Not sure about high pressures.

Comment: I agree, especially if the data presented are faked. Here is an interesting interview with Jorge Hirsch who astonishingly  leans towards that LK-99 is legit! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQnDatnAWP4

Comment: Give it a few months and there will be plenty of replications and advancements if it is real. The cuprate superconductors showed that 30 years ago when the internet was in its infancy.

Comment: @JonCuster You are right, gold, silver and copper are not superconductors  but are diamagnetic. But again these are very weak diamagnetic materials.

Comment: What I'm looking with my question is if there is a strong diamagnetic material that is not superconductive as an argument against LK-99 of being a superconductor.

Comment: Bulk, pure graphite is a strong diamagnetic material. Bulk superconductivity seems to be associated with intercalation with other elements, but I'm not completely up on it all.

Comment: @JonCuster Strangely enough,  this here also claims that pyrolytic graphite is also superconductive at 27 C https://revistapesquisa.fapesp.br/en/superconductor-at-room-temperature/

Comment: Hype for LK99 is unjustified (not only, it is also a case of "bad science", see e.g. https://youtu.be/zl-AgmoZ5mo ). Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/774233/226902

Comment: Let's wait for  an independent  paper(s) and published in an actual Journal to review formally and disprove by experiment replication LK-99. Do that the proper way and not by social media opinions even if they are from sixty symbols. Bat yes I agree so far things got south for LK-99. I can't take it out of my mind these authors being so naïve and that they did it just to get rich from superconductor stock market rise?

Comment: @Markoul11 it is very clear that LK99 does not have the claimed properties: this is a Nature article [LK-99 isn’t a superconductor — how science sleuths solved the mystery](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-02585-7), see also [Claimed superconductor LK-99 is an online sensation — but replication efforts fall short](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-02481-0)