# LK-99 a total waste?

Tags: material-science, superconductivity

It looks like [LK-99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LK-99) is not what it was purported to be. Disappointing but not surprising.
However did anything of substance or new ways or approaching the problem brought to light in the way it was theorized to function?

I'm specifically thinking of how some other recent super conductors only functioning under great pressure and how LK-99 was supposed to have solved that issue by Cu2+ substitution of Pb2+. Was this a novel idea or a method already used in other areas?

Comment: [Context](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-02585-7).

Comment: "However did anything of substance or new ways or approaching the problem brought to light in the way it was theorized to function?" I'd guess not, but this is probably pretty heavily opinion-based (or unanswerable). "Was this a novel idea or a method already used in other areas?" No. Or yes. It depends on what part of the  method you mean. With respect to the first half of your compound question, probably mostly "no."

Comment: [Bad Science and Room Temperature Superconductors](https://youtu.be/zl-AgmoZ5mo). See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/775226/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/774233/226902